# Shifting the frame of root view controller, containing a tab bar

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

The application has a `Tabbar Controller` as its `rootViewController`. Now the requirement is on click of a button in the `navigation bar`, another view should come half way into the screen without any tab bar, and the other half should have the original view that has the `tab bar` in it. Is this possible to create?
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:

I did try

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake();
```

but the problem is, another view wont be seen in this, as the whole window frame is being shifted.

EDIT 2:

I have added a dummy pic of the requirement.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the solution to it. 
On click of the button,

```
objThird.view.frame = CGRectMake(120, 0, 320, 480);

UIView *windowVIew = [self.tabBarController.view superview];
[windowVIew addSubview:objThird.view];
self.tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 0, 320, 480);
```

`objThird` = Object of new view that i want when the button is pressed.
`self.tabBarController.view superview` = Gives you the window view. thus now you can add your view to the window.

And the rest is just playing with the frames of the views.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view by subclassing UIView and show that in your current view controller in the first half.

You can use UIKit animation for animating the view if needed.

Comment: it would really help if you would elucidate a bit on that.